# Best way to get all subdirectories containing a file in s3 using python and boto

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

Is there any way to do a wildcard search on a bucket in s3? using python and boto.
I need to copy all subdirectories that contain a specific file, what is the best approach?

Comment: S3 doesn't support searching filenames and also it technically doesn't have directories either (prefixes are not directories, S3 is a flat object store). You will need to iterate every object in the bucket and do your own filtering on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

The [`list_buckets_v2()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) command does not accept wildcards.

The closest option is the ability to pass a `Prefix` and `Delimiter`, which effectively works like looking in a particular sub-directory.

You will need to write your own logic to determine which **objects** (not directories) to copy. If you wish to copy whole subdirectories, the code will need to loop through each object in that path and copy the object individually.

If your requirement is to "copy all subdirectories that contain a specific file", you would need to:

- Do a first-pass by listing all objects
- Loop through the object keys (filenames), looking for your desired filename at the end of the Key (from the last slash (`/`) onwards)
- If the filename is found, add the prefix (every *up to* the last slash) to a list
- For each path that was added to the list, perform another `list_objects_v2()` passing the path as a prefix, and call the `copy_object()` command for each object

(You could achieve the above with only a single `list_objects_v2()` call, but the above is logically simpler. Your choice.)

Comment: Something to note for performance - querying the `/` prefix with a delimiter of `/` will return all top level objects and prefixes, but on the server side this has to scan every single object in the bucket, making those types of requests slow.